# Selecting Last Immediate Child

Tags: jquery, xml, querypath

My XML Structure is like

```
<root>
  <elem1>..</elem1>
  <elem1>..</elem1>
  *<elem1>..</elem1>*
  <elem2>
    <elem1>..</elem1>
    <elem1>..</elem1>
    ¬ <elem1>..</elem1> ¬
  </elem2>
</root>
```

**I need to select the last elem1 of the immediate child of root (marked with * *).**

I want to do it in QueryPath - http://querypath.org. But JQuery syntaxes could also help.

```
$root->find('elem1')->last();
$root->find('elem1:last);
$root->find('elem1:last-child);
```

All the above three selects the elem1 marked with ¬

Comment: With jQuery you might be able to use `$('root > elem1:last-of-type')`, as for QueryPath I have no idea, though.

Comment: [Proof of concept for my previous comment](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/RehZ7/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works

```
$root->find('elem1:last-of-type');
```

Thanks David Thomas for Proof of Concept 
http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/RehZ7/

Answer (score 2):

You can use `last` method:

```
$('root > elem1').last();
```

By looking at QueryPath API it seems you can code:

```
$root->children('elem1')->last()
```

Answer (score 0):

[last()](http://api.jquery.com/last/) method that reduces the set of matched elements to the final one in the set, can do it for you like below;

```
$('root > elem1').last();
```

OR

You can use [:last-child Selector](http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/) that selects all elements that are the last child of their parent.

```
$('root elem1:last-child');
```